# How can I find a discontinuous open function from subsets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to subsets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ induced with the euclidean topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean topology and let $f:A \rightarrow B$. Can $f$ be open, but not closed nor continuous? I have not been able to find such a function. Are there any subsets that I could look at which would help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $A=\Bbb R^2$, $$B=(\Bbb Q\times\{0\})\cup\big((\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\times\{1\}\big);,$$ and

$$f:A\to B:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\begin{cases}
\langle x,0\rangle,&\text{if }x\in\Bbb Q\\
\langle x,1\rangle,&\text{if }x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;.
\end{cases}$$

Showing that $f$ is not continuous is very straightforward. To show that $f$ is open, note that if $U$ is an open nbhd of $\langle x,y\rangle$ in $\Bbb R^2$, there are open intervals $I$ and $J$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $$\langle x,y\rangle\in I\times J\subseteq U\;.$$ To show that $f$ is not closed, consider the graph of $y=\dfrac1x$.

Comment: I am having trouble seeing that f is open. take for example the open square $(0,1)^2$, which would map to $(0,1) \times \{0,1\}$. How is that subset of B open?

Comment: @user1876508: That subset of $B$ is the intersection with $B$ of the open set $(0,1)\times\Bbb R$ in the plane, so it’s open in the subspace topology on $B$. However, that subset of $B$ isn’t the image of $(0,1)^2$; the image of $(0,1)^2$ does not contain $\left\langle\frac12,1\right\rangle$ for instance. The actual image of $(0,1)^2$ is not open, because I didn’t define $B$ as I intended to; I’ve fixed it now.